# Python system call that works on windows and linux

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I have a strange issue, that I cannot seem to resolve

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

exeLocation = "../Engine.exe"

# Works on windows
proc = Popen([exeLocation, arg1, arg2],stdout=PIPE,shell=True])
(out,err) = proc.communicate()

# Works on Linux
proc = Popen(" ".join([exeLocation, arg1, arg2]),stdout=PIPE,shell=True])
(out,err) = proc.communicate()
```

For some reason, a '..' is not a command error thrown if you run the linux version on windows.

For some reason the command passed of "exeLocation arg1 arg2" wont work in linux, using the windows version.

I need a way to perform this operation on both platforms, using the same code.

Comment: Why you wouldn't use `if`? like `if os.name == 'posix':`, `elif os.name == 'nt':`

Comment: I figure that is a solution, but a nasty one. I find it hard to believe I cant make a system call and read the output stream, with the same code, in python.

Comment: Are you sure that your code can work? `shell=True]`?

Comment: The windows code works on windows, and the linux code works on linux. That I am sure of. My examples are not far from my actual code

Comment: All right. but if you don't like `if` and `elif`. What do you think about `proc = Popen([exeLocation, arg1, arg2],stdout=PIPE,shell=True]) if os.name == 'posix' else proc = Popen(" ".join([exeLocation, arg1, arg2]),stdout=PIPE,shell=True])`? only one line.

Comment: I will happily use that solution for the time being, but I hope someone finds a solution and posts it, or I find one and come back and post it. Thank you for the quick fix.

Comment: However I have no idea about how to do that without `if`.So I can only give you that solution :)

Comment: unrelated: using a relative path is not recommended, pass the full path instead. Note: the current working directory may differ from the directory your script is stored.

Answer (score 1):

The portable code should use a list argument (drop `shell=True`) or it should pass the command as a string if `shell=True` is required.

Don't use relative paths such as `../`: either pass the absolute path (including the file extension) or rely on `PATH` envvar and use something like: `program = 'engine'`.